# 'Invalid Verb' error only when Calling Inkscape as a subprocess

Tags: node.js, subprocess, inkscape

When I call the following in the command line it works like a charm:

```sh
inkscape --with-gui --batch-process --export-filename=- \
    --actions="select-all;ObjectToPath" \
    /full/path/to/example.svg
```

But when I open Node.js and make the same call in a subprocess like so:

```js
const cp = require("child_process");
var child = cp.spawn(
    "/usr/bin/inkscape",
    [
        "--with-gui",
        "--batch-process",
        "--export-filename=-",
        '--actions="select-all;ObjectToPath"',
        "/full/path/to/example.svg",
    ],
    {
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        detached: true,
        stdio: "inherit",
    }
);
```

I get the following error:

```sh
Unable to find: "select-all
verbs_action: Invalid verb: "select-all
Unable to find: ObjectToPath"
verbs_action: Invalid verb: ObjectToPath"
```

and the file is returned (printed to stdout) unchanged.  Any Idea why the verbs are not found when running Inkscape as a subprocess but not calling it directly from the terminal?   I get this same error on ubuntu (20.04) and OSX using the latest Inkscape (1.0.1+r73).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cp.spawn` with an array of arguments, you don't need to internally quote `"select-all;ObjectToPath"` like you would with a shell. (In a shell, the quotes prevent the shell from tokenizing the command line into two lines. Due to the same mechanism - or lack thereof - attempting to use shell variables such as `$$` or environment variables such as `$PATH` would fail when you use  `cp.spawn`, since there's nothing to parse that.)

I would imagine

```
const cp = require("child_process");
var child = cp.spawn(
  "/usr/bin/inkscape",
  [
    "--with-gui",
    "--batch-process",
    "--export-filename=-",
    "--actions=select-all;ObjectToPath",
    "/full/path/to/example.svg",
  ],
  {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    detached: true,
    stdio: "inherit",
  },
);
```

would do the trick for you.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm :)